# Этимология названий рек

Tags: этимология

*Этимология названий рек*

Почему названия всех крупных рек, впадающих в Черное и Азовское моря, начинаются на букву "Д"? Дунай, Днестр, Днепр, Дон. Да и крупный приток Днепра Десна тоже начинается на Д.

Comment: Простите, что осмелился поправить последнее предложение, просто Двина значительно севернее и то, что из множества рек на всей этой территории её название начинается на Д, совсем ни о чём не говорит. Это касается и Западной, и Северной Двины.

Comment: Голосуйте за вопрос! По-моему, он очень хороший! С Новым Годом всех!

Answer (score 2):

Ну, короче так. Никаких серьезных аргументов против скифо-сарматского происхождения я не нашел. Учитывая общность названий с морфом "дон" на обширнейшей территории (по одной из версии - Дунай - сюда же) и безусловную древность названия (греки задолго до болгар называли Дон Танаисом), можно говорить о только о скифском происхождении, зона распространения в период максимального расцвета (IV-III век до Н.Э.)  которых хорошо совпадает с ареалом распространения гидронима.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Википедии более подробно - в статье Дон.

> Название Дон происходит от арийского корня *dānu-: авест. dānu «река»,
>   др.-инд. dānu «капель, роса, сочащаяся жидкость»[3][4]. Русское
>   название реки произошло от скифо-сарматского слова dānu того же корня.
>   Осетинский язык, наследник скифо-сарматского, содержит однокоренное
>   слово дон («река, вода»). В. И. Абаев считает, что «переход dān → don
>   произошёл не ранее XIII—XIV веков, когда осетины (аланы) уже не были
>   массово представлены на юге России. Поэтому русскую форму Дон нельзя
>   связывать непосредственно с современным осетинским don»[4], эти слова
>   родственны через скифо-сарматский язык.
>
> В Осетии, которая является одной из частей исторической Алании, по сей
>   день все реки пишутся с морфемой -дон в постпозиции: Ардон, Фиагдон,
>   Урсдон, Кармадон и т. д. Реки Днепр, Днестр, Донец и, возможно, Дунай,
>   имеют схожую скифо-сарматскую этимологию[5][6], так как находились на
>   территориях, населённых скифами.
>
> Донец — уменьшительно-ласкательная форма названия Дон, возникшая в
>   древнерусском языке. Это название имеют несколько рек, большинство из
>   которых впадают в Дон или в его приток Северский Донец или являются их
>   рукавами: Северский Донец, Липовый Донец, Мёртвый Донец, Сажной Донец,
>   Сухой Донец. Донец — древнерусское (X—XIV века) название реки Уды.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD

Comment: Спасибо, информация интересная. Если "Д" в названиях означает "большая река", то представляет интерес смысловая нагрузка правой части названий, за буквой "Д".  Д - Унай ( Река Связующая, Д - Уния), Д - Непр ( Река Непрядва), протекает через исконные льноводческие регионы, например, город Смоленск и смоленскую область... Случайный гость.

Comment: И прочтите слово дно,как вы его написали )))да на стар .слав т е ДЪНО, это вы сейчас не читаете ъ знак, но тогда это была гласная буква и читается она как раз как -О в этом слове )))Дон выписывается.

Answer (score 1):

В названиях данных рек присутствует основа *дон (дн, дун),* которая имеет скифо-сарматское происхождение (dānu) и обозначает *вода* либо *река*.

Comment: Десна-то тут явно другого происхождения, славянского. Двина, вероятно, тоже.  А насчет Дуная и Дона - да, есть версия об общности этимологии, но не более чем версия. Не самая правдоподобная.

Comment: Предлагаю расширить анализ, включив в перечень названий рек  реку Даугава. Северный  пул рек : Даугава, Двина, Десна. Случайный гость.

Comment: К вопросу о том, почему Днестр назван Днестром.  Контролирующее реку население поклонялось  Стрий-Богу. Именем своего Бога назывались реки и бытовое окружение. Поэтому население плывет по реке ДнеСТР, по СТРемнине, и, конечно же, на СТРугах.  Там, где население поклоняется Одину, там река называется Одер, и, плывут по этой реке, конечно же на лОДках, по завОДям. Случайный гость.

Answer (score -1):

Днепр -дон аэб ро- скачущая река, имеются в виду знаменитые днепровские пороги.
Днестр- дон ест ро – ест, естей, есть (наличиствует) ро- река, дорога. Судоходная река.
Истр-   ест (истая, настоящая) ро.
Дунай  -Данай, Даная – по имени богини вод Дану, предводительницы данава. Туатха Данаан у кельтов. Тхъе- Бог у адыгов, окончание -ан, -он означает женскую линию рода у осетин .
Десна - рукав, приток реки- от дез, десница, возможно "одесную", но реки Десна- левые притоки Днепра и Пахры.
Слово "дон" известно с древнейших времен на территориях расселения племенного объединения даев, распространившихся на протяжении прим. С 15 го по 6- ой века до н.э. по основным направлениям на запад до Египта, по именем мада, мадай, мидийцы, на сев.   Запад вдоль побережий Черного и Каспийских морей до Фракии, под именем меды, медовеевцы( вей- множество), медозюи( меда зоа- сыновья Меды), Аситаи (осетины) и от Малой Мидии через исторический Адурбадаган (Мазандеран, Гилян, Талыш) на север Каспия через Ас тархан  ( ближнее торжище) и далее по Волге и Дону, где прозвались рось (ро, ра – река, дорога).   На север, должно быть, ушли сторонники Гуаматы( Гуатамы), разбитого Дарием в 522г. до н.э.- Авеста против Вед.
В значении «место»-  тирдон- место, вместилище для стрел (колчан), зиндон- место для нечистот, лона дон –место расположения гнезда и т.п.
В значении «земля»- дон в осетинском языке (Аси таи- ближние даи)- земля.   В мидийских прозваниях царей Набу-ха дона сар- Набу – объединённой земли (местности) господин, Ас – сар ха дон – Ашшура – господин объединённой земли (местности).   В русском- дно.
Дон, наверное, упрощенное название реки. У алан свои традиции.
Северные реки прозываются по такой же схеме- характерная черта + ва –вода, река, например: Эжва, Колва, Дау-га-ва и т.п.
Влта - ва, Влга- ва ( на которой Асгард- обитель норманского Одина, а защита асов на территории росьалани - на Волге) -та же схема.
На Кавказе, в местностях расселения даев, Кура (ро) ку- гора, склон горы, ро- река.
Особенность гидронима Кубань - отсутствие в названии значения "река". 
Ку-гора, бан, бин -дно, низ. Кубань, Кобань (ко- и есть горная долина на осетинском), горная долина, традиционное место расселения кавказцев, потому
и регион Краснодарского края и Адыгеи называется Кубань.
Интересны, с точки зрения этнографии, археологические находки в с. Кобань
В местах расселение сарматов (саирма- светлоголовые) Ростовской области, река Ея, Куго ея- ку склон горы, го- текущая (движущаяся) река.
Море Азов- вода азов, азами еще недавно называли медов на Черноморском побережье Кавказа.
Река Шахе к районе Б.Сочи - на языке даев -движущаяся к морю.
Гидронимы, топонимы и пр. -нимы, имена- надежный индикатор ареалов расселения  тех или иных народов в прошлом и настоящем. Надо только правильно читать эти имена.

Answer (score -3):

Возможно, здесь болгарский след. В топонимике Древней Руси имеются *болгарские двойники*, названия которых соответствуют названиям городов **Болгарской Руси**. На Дунае в Болгарии располагались *Киевец*, *Смоленск*, *Новеград*; в Болгарии был также и *Словенск*, — соответственно Славянск на Украине, печально известный бесчинствами гиркинских террористов. Переселенцы из Болгарии брали в новую Русь свои старые названия городов. (Вообще, есть мнения, что многие события, описываемые в "Повестях временных лет", в действительности относятся к Болгарии, а не к Киевской Руси, и включены в ПВЛ, как фикция.) Точно так же и полноводные реки — Днепр, Днестр, Дон — эти *переселенцы* называли, как и свой покинутый **Д**-У-**Н**-АЙ. Впоследствии основа **Д**-**Н** трансформировалась в **Д**-**Н**-ЕПР, **Д**-**Н**-ЕСТР, **Д**-О-**Н**. У Днестра есть и другие названия — греческое Тирас, турецкое Турла; Днепр по-другому названию — Славутич; а Дон у греков известен под именем Танаис.

Comment: Да какие болгары на Дону? Они и Болгарию только в четвертом веке только пришли из степей.

Comment: @behemothus . Батенька ! Почитайте материалы о Болгарской Руси , а уж потом минусуйте и возражайте . В поисковике найдёте . И христианство в Киевскую Русь первоначально проникло именно из Болгарии , а не из Византии . И откуда Вы можете знать , что Дон назывался Доном до появления на Руси болгар ?! К тому же , тут речь идёт не только о Доне .

Comment: Ну понятно. Сразу на личночсти и на поисковики. ))) Я про Дон до болгар ничего не говорил. Это, простите, Ваши тараканы. Но если Вы даете версию об общности **болгарских** названий, то хотя бы могли примерно посмотреть, где и когда это могло произойти. Ну это помимо того, что версии, не основанные исключительно на фонетическом сходстве, без учета общих фонетических процессов просто отвергаются в приличном обществе. И Вам следовало бы знать, что гидронимы обычно сохраняются в неизменном виде дольше всего, Новое население наследует название предшественника. Так что тут вернее всего еще раньше.

Comment: Спасибо, информация интересная. Если "Д" означает "большая река", то правая часть названий интересна с точки зрения смысловой нагрузки. Дунай - Река Связующая ( Уния), Днепр - Река Непрядва ( протекает через исконные льноводческие регионы, например, Смоленск и Смоленскую область).....

Comment: @следопыт Вслед за Бегемотусом восклицаю - О. боже! Какой-такой Славянск на Украине? Это поселение, возникло как крепость Тор, в конце 17 века, возвели его для охраны южнорусских окраин от набегов кочевников и татар крымских, буджакских и таманских. Позже к нему прилипло название Солеварск(из торских озер выпаривали соль, был солидный промысел), возможно из этого названия и возник Славянск, скорее всего, волевым порядком. По крайней мере в Славянском городском краеведении именно такая версия. И при чем тут И.И.Гиркин?Думаю, если будете бандеровщину гнать на ресурсе, Вас просто забанят надолго.

Comment: *Какие "Болгары Руси???" Болгары - это тюркский народ. Нет ничего хуже, безапелляционных идиотов* - это да. Хуже только безграмотные анонимы

Answer (score -3):

Не буду столь многословен, как предыдущие эксперты, да и простят меня лингвисты, которые зачастую подгоняют нужные звуки, чтобы получить нужное им слово нужного  им языка и оправдать этим липовую версию.
Все эти названия рек имеют в себе одно древне-славянское слово "дно" или его производные, почему-то это никто просто не хочет замечать? А само это слово  ДНО идет корнями в глубокую древность, думаю, во времена общности индо-европейских языков; возможно, и означает оно первоначально ― *глубина, глубоко* и т. д. Так что лично я вижу в этих названиях рек чисто славянское происхождение!
Впрочем, и про принадлежность языка скифов к иранской группе у меня тоже большие сомнения.

Comment: Просто потому, что славянское слово "дно" ничего общего с этимологией гидронимов не имеет. )))) Названия много старше славян вообще и славян в тех местах, о которых идет речь - тем более.

Comment: это кто сказал, что  не было? а где  доказательства? ))не хочу  переводить  тему  в бесконечный спор, уверен  вы не докажите  ,что славян там  не было или их предков, весь этот ареал  в истории  занимает  очень  интересное место,   с глубокой  древности  до момента якобы  начала  древней  Руси, и интересности эти имеют  одну общность -а именно  что никто  ,никогда не описал   населяющих их народы! ссылаясь  на дикость   сменяющих  друг друга  племен, начиная  от скифов, которых  плавно  уничтожают  савроматы, которых  уничтожают  гунны  и так до древней Руси

Comment: и  как не странно, все они дикие  и по ныне )))они были  и именно  там! из воздуха  народ  с численностью в 500 миллионов  не мог взяться )))и это древний  народ!

Comment: *это кто сказал, что не было?*  - историки))) Насчет доказательств - тут я с вами согласен. Без доказательств вашу гипотезу обсуждать больше не буду.

Comment: ну и правильно, без доказательной базы -это всего лишь версия, и она сомнительна на мой взгляд, учитывая те факты, которые мы имеем сегодня, да и в древности они проскакивают то там  то тут, другое дело  название племен, славян как само названия никогда  не было, однозначно, но были  венеды, анты и другие! Но слово "Дно" сохранилось и в нашем языке  со временем общности индо-европейских языков, это факт тоже

Comment: Ну а зачем вы её тогда выставляете на посмешище?

Comment: с  чего  это?)))это просто  одна  из версий, ни чем не отличающаяся от других высказанных тут, с такими же  основаниями, не больше  не меньше! даже  те из версий, которые  указывают  на Асетинские корни, в которой дон -река  с асетинского языка, на самом  деле  в те времена  (5 тыс  лет  назад )могли  иметь другое значение, такое  же как и дно к примеру и вовсе  не реку ))

Comment: Ну как же не отличающаяся-то? Ваша-то **опровергается** на раз-два. А вы все, что можете, так это говорить нехорошие слова про лингвистов, которые знают, какие звуки какими заменяются в разных языках.

Comment: опровергаются чем? )))у меня  есть знакомый лингвист, и таких  вовсе не один  и не два, который  точно  так же  легко подводит  эти  слова  к славянским языкам  и фино-угорким, в общем  как я понял, главное  какая  задача  перед  ним  стоит  на выходе )))А скивский  язык  не известен, выводы  о нем сделаны  по якобы  их именам,да ещё в греческих  источниках и написанных по гречески, в которых  эллиада  повторяться больше  тысячалетие ,не зависимо от автора и вечный враг  Персия )))

Comment: в качестве примера лингвистов, о которых я говорю, можно взять Тадеуша Воланский,можете его труды  прочесть и попробовать их опровергнуть, или Мавро  Орбини )))

Comment: Мне не интересны лингвисты  в вашем пересказе. А сам я, простите, имею других авторитетов. Ваша версия опровергается историей. Ну какие "500 миллионов"? Вы примерно представляете численность всего человечества в скифские времена? На рубеже эр людей всего было 300 мил., причем основная масса - в Китае и Индии, как и сейчас. Ну и масса орфографических ошибок пониманию ваших опусов не способствует.

Comment: 500 миллионов -это было  про современных  славян вообще-то, и какой  историей, что опровергается? Скалигеровской? )))

Comment: А какое это имеет значение, сколько сейчас славян? Историей опровергается ваша версия, что названия - славянские, они древнее славян на полтысячелетия - как минимум. Предки славян не говорили на славянских языках. А греки предавали скифские названия. Их ареал хорошо совпадает  с зоной распространения скифской культуры. А что вы можете сказать за свою "версию", кроме того, что нравится вас и каким-то неизвестным миру филологам-дилетантам?  Остальное - читайте источники, устал я уже.

Comment: непосредственно прямое! ничего  не опровергается! сплошная  ложь и политика  и ноль истории! про язык, на котором  они не говорили -вообще  долгая  история и язык  этот на много  древнее. Греки )))ничего  не передавали, ни одного  древнего  источника!-все фальшивое  и не старше 17 века, более  того  даже  в них  нет  ничего  о ареале их обитания -по тому что  они там никогда не были! и даже  скифские  украшения будто греки делали ))но такие же  украшения на Алтае находят, датировкой когда  греков  ещё не существовало

Comment: Простите, это уже истерика. Вы Фоменку перечитали и иже с ним. Вы заодно с топонимикой хотите еще и историю раком поставить? Не много на себя берете? Повторяю, читайте серьезные источники. Славяне появились не ранее начала новой эры, их язык настолько отличался от современного, что вы бы его просто на распознали.

Comment: И еще маленький штришок. Слова "дно"  само по себе довольно новое. Было "дъно", образовавшееся от "Дъбно". От неко произошел топоним "Дубно" ("Добно"), Ну  ладно, беглый гласный  мог исчезнуть (хотя не в этом случае, видимо), но "Б"-то куда делось во всех топонимах сразу? Вообще гидронимы названий обычно не меняют, это как-раз  очень важный и стабильный инструмент  изучения исторических ареалов.

Comment: но  если  бы вы писали  и Днепр на пра слав. то вам  бы также  следовало  закрывать  каждый  слог  гласной ъ (о) те  Дънепъръ)))но это не суть, про Фоменко  и прочих  речи  вообще не идет, хотя  и у них  доля  сути  имеется. Я о другом, не скифские  это названия, и вообще  язык  скифов не факт, а скорее  вовсе, не иранской  семьи ))вот почитайте, если  вы о серьезной научной литературе  так  ратуете)))https://dnagen.wordpress.com/2018/01/28/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%8B/

Comment: да и ещё  монет, вы правы  на счет  слова  ДНО, как ДЪНО -именно  так оно записывается на старо славянском )))это мертвая  ныне  гласная Ъ,читается не иначе  как сейчас О ,и это ещё  не все,как не странно это будет  звучать  это множественное число )))а слово  ДЪБНО не славянское, а латинский  или литовский  аналог, и вообще  вики -это не подходящий источник для  подобных  сравнений, не пользуйтесь им лучше